# Why can I view some Unix executable files in Mac OS X and not others?

Tags: git, bash, shell, unix, binary

I am on a Macbook Pro on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite). When I go to `/usr/bin`, `git` is there as a unix executable file. When I open it up in Sublime Text, all I get is unreadable machine code. However, when I open up a different Unix executable file—in my case, a shell script I had just written, but there are others—I am able to open up the file in Sublime Text and view the contents of the script. I have checked the permissions for both files, and they are the same. Why is there different behavior when opening up some files?

Comment: This is not specific to a Mac and OS X, it is the same on UNIX and Linux, and to some extent on Windows. Compare a Windows .bat file to a Windows .exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Executable files may be scripts (in which case you can read the text), or binaries (which are ELF formatted machine code). Your shell script is a script; `git` is an ELF binary.

You can use the `file` command to see more detail. For example, on my nearest Linux system:

```
$ file /usr/local/bin/git
/usr/local/bin/git: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to making an executable file a binary? Also, are binaries made from compiling scripts?

Comment: ELF binaries are produced by the linker from source code written in a language like C or C++. I guess the "advantage" is if you want to write in C, you end up creating binary executables. Scripts are not compiled, they remain readable scripts.

Comment: How would you go about writing an executable file in C or C++ though? I just assumed that the only executable files you could make were some form of shell scripts. Or would you use C to write a shell script in a different shell?

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. A C program is compiled from C source code to machine code, no shell script code involved. To do this, follow any introductory C or C++ programming tutorial.